# Android NDK and JNI native method not found

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working setting up the NDK for my android project.
I have an android project with a textview that outputs to the emulator
"Output="
I have a native function called `somefunc()` that i add to this string and it throws an error stating.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2242): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.ndktest.MainActivity.somefunc:()I
```

I have **three files** that I believe are needed.  **MainActivity.java** , **test.c, and Android.mk**.

In **test.c** I have

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_ndktest_MainActivity_somefunc(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj)
{
return 2;
}
```

And **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILE := test.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ndktest;

import com.ndktest.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static
{
  System.loadLibrary("test");
}
public native int somefunc();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    String s = "Ouput="+somefunc();
    tv.setText(s);
    this.setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

I understand from the various guides online  that spelling mistakes are the most common cause of this error.  I have tried my best to check for a spelling mistake in the package and in the c function code and so far I don't see it.  I also am able to run "ndk-build" on the makefile and it compiles without errors.  It produces libtest and i load the library.  I have tried a try catch around it and the try passes for the system load library.  So i assume there is a spelling mistake or an error in how i named my c function.  I have read that the c function should be called in Java_[package with underscores instead dots]*[java class]*[function name].  I think i am abiding by this.  I apologize i the first half of question looks like a stereotypical "solve this for me" question. I just wanted the code there so it shows what the packages are called and what the make looks like.
Thank you

Comment: There should be messages in the logcat about the library load attempt - you can ignore a warning about jnionload, but you should see an indication of either success or failure there.  Technically your return type should be jint not int, but they may in practice be the same.  Sometimes if you get really stuck, starting from the hello-jni sample and morphing it into your needs one change at a time between tests can be useful in figuring out where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, hello-jni works perfectly, i feel that there must be something wrong with how i set up my project.  I will retry making a new project and seeing if that works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be your issue, but I've been fighting several hours with a similar problem. My problem was that my native functions contained underscores (for example 'native int get_result()'). Everything was ok in the jni naming (Java_mypackage_myclass_get_result ...), but JNI didn't detect that 'get_result' was the name of the function, so I was getting an UnsatisfiedLinkerror. The solution was to remove all underscores from the functions (say convert get_result() to getResult()).

(I was using 'javah -jni' to create the header files, and I didn't  got any warning)

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the correct prototypes for your native functions by calling

`javah -classpath bin/classes -d jni com.ndktest.MainActivity`

from your source directory. This will create a header `com_ndktest_MainActivity.h` which can be included in your C file.

(BTW: if your native file is compiled as C++ you would need `extern "C" {...}`)

Comment: This problem can also happen when your 'System.loadLibrary' call is missing or in a class that is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing from

> JNIEXPORT int JNICALL

to

> JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL